# Can I bind the instance to non-static method immediately after creating instance of ES6-class?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

Is it some way to assemble first two rows into one? I am not feeling comfortable to force users of `MarkupPreprocessingHelper` write two rows...

```
let markupPreprocessingHelper = new MarkupPreprocessingHelper(config);
let preprocessTemplates = markupPreprocessingHelper.takeCareAboutMarkupPreprocessing.bind(markupPreprocessingHelper);

gulp.task('Development run', gulp.series(
   preprocessTemplates,
   // ...
));
```

Comment: Why not have an instance property on `markupPreprocessingHelper` that points to the bound function. Then users can use: `markupPreprocessingHelper.somePreBoundFunction`

Comment: @MarkMeyer, thank you for the comment. Bound function? The`somePreBoundFunction() { this.takeCareAboutMarkupPreprocessing.bind(this); }` will not work, but do you mean something like this?

Comment: No, not quite what I had in mind. I posted an example below of what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make a rebound copy of the function and save it as an instance property, you can then pass it around and users won't need to bind it manually:

```js
function someClass(name){
    this.name = name
    // make a prebound copy of myFunction
    this.preBound = this.myFunction.bind(this)
}

someClass.prototype.myFunction = function(){
    console.log(this.name)
}

let p = new someClass("Mark")

// now you can pass a reference of it around without losing the binding
let fn = p.preBound
setTimeout(fn, 500)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Accepting answer and upvote.